# How can I pass Paypal ipn custom and invoice variables?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to use the paypal ipn to pass variables from when the user clicks on my button to when I get the ipn notification.  I'm currently testing this on the sandbox.  I get the IPN request just fine, but when it comes in, it is missing the two variables, custom and invoice, that I passed on the form.  This is an example of what my form looks like:

```
<form id="paypal-form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="23424234488"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="basic"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="24817238724"/>
</form>
```

When I get the IPN, custom and invoice are not defined on the request.  How can I get these values to pass through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the two variables were on the request of the incoming ipn, but not on the response from the ipn verification.  Just some confusion on my part.

Comment: Are you sure? The custom variable paypal must be sent back. Documentation here http://bit.ly/Ny1SXU

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I've found that our invoice number supplied is returned to us in the IPN as the POST field '**invoice_number**'  PayPal's IPN simulator does not appear to offer this field which was counterproductive to our sandbox testing.